# How to draw separate circle in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone

How can I draw a circle like this, 2 colors in 2 parts. I'm coding in xaml

[image]

```
<Ellipse Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Height="300">

                    </Ellipse>

                    <Path VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Brown" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="59,150">
                                    <ArcSegment SweepDirection="Clockwise" Size="141,80" Point="341,150"/>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
```

I try it, and the above Path not full a part 1. Help me try draw it!

Comment: draw two paths one over the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also make use of the following...

```
   <Grid Height="200" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Ellipse Fill="#FFE1B631"  />
        <Path Data="M93.88768,0 C136.17198,0 172.32661,26.244247 186.95134,63.33252 L187.77536,65.5 0,65.5 0.82401276,63.33252 C15.44875,26.244247 51.603378,0 93.88768,0 z" Fill="#FFFD450F" Height="60.26" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,1.31,8,0"/> 
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: How set Data of Path like this? @Sankarann

Answer (score 18):

Here ya go:

```
<Canvas>
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" Width="300" Height="300" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Red" />
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" Width="300" Height="300" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Yellow">
        <Ellipse.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0 100 300 300" />
        </Ellipse.Clip>
    </Ellipse>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="150" Width="300" Height="200" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Transparent">
        <Rectangle.Clip>
            <EllipseGeometry Center="150, 50" RadiusX="150" RadiusY="150" />
        </Rectangle.Clip>
    </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

The first canvas element draws a red circle, the second element draws a yellow circle over top and clips it, the third element draws the black line through the middle. Here's the result:

[image]

EDIT: Actually thinking about this some more the two ellipses can be done with a single ellipse and a linear gradient brush:

```
<Ellipse Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" Width="300" Height="300" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.3333" />
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.3333" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
```

Comment: What other ways use Path draw a part of circle?

Comment: A linear gradient! Brilliant!